# Initializers of a Class Extending UICollectionView (Swift 3.2)

Tags: swift, collectionview, initializer

I am coding in Swift 3.2. I have a class called `EventCollectionView` that extends `UICollectionView`. An instance of this class is an 'event' and I would like to initialize it with three UIImages, images that display the event photo, event info, and event tickets.

However, when I try to call `super.init()` in the custom initializer I get an error message saying 'Must call a designated initializer of the superclass UICollectionView.' I have tried implementing `super.init(frame:CGRect)` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Below is the first part of my `EventCollectionView` class.

```
var eventPhoto: UIImage?
var eventInfo: UIImage?
var eventTickets: UIImage?

//Initializers
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

init?(eventPhoto: UIImage?, eventInfo: UIImage?, eventTickets: UIImage?) {
    super.init()       //Where the error occurs
    self.eventPhoto = eventPhoto
    self.eventInfo = eventInfo
    self.eventTickets = eventTickets
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you going to initialize `EventCollectionView` programmatically or by storyboard/xib?

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini By storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to initialize such `EventCollectionView` by storyboard you should inject those parameters in another way like:

```
class EventCollectionView:UICollectionView {
  var eventPhoto: UIImage?
  var eventInfo: UIImage?
  var eventTickets: UIImage?

  func setup(eventPhoto: UIImage?, eventInfo: UIImage?, eventTickets: UIImage?) {
    self.eventPhoto = eventPhoto
    self.eventInfo = eventInfo
    self.eventTickets = eventTickets
  }
}
```

then you should call `setup` anytime after the initialization such as:

```
import UIKit

class YourViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var collectionView:EventCollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // setup whatever here:
    let photo:UIImage? = nil
    let info:UIImage? = nil
    let tickets:UIImage? = nil
    collectionView.setup(eventPhoto: photo, eventInfo: info, eventTickets: tickets)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes a lot more sense!!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple developer documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618053-init), it looks like the appropriate `init` method signature should be: `init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout)`. For example, your `init` method could become:

```
init?(eventPhoto: UIImage?, eventInfo: UIImage?, eventTickets: UIImage?) {

    let flowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionViewFrame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)

    super.init(frame: collectionViewFrame, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)  
    ...
}
```